# If a set of n vectors are linearly dependant then n-1 vectors of the same set must be linearly independant .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, independence

Is This true or not ?
If yes , please provide a proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show some of your own effort in solving this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Counter-example over the field of reals (or field of rationals, etc.)
$S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}10 \\ 20 \\ 30 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}100 \\ 200 \\ 300 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Comment: how can you find the rank of a set of vectors if they were linearly dependant